# Changing the Cell color of the UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I trying to change the color of the cells that populate the UITableView       cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor]; but it still remains black for the cell.

```
 -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

if (tofriend) {

    if (indexPath.section==0){


        static NSString *CellIdentifier;
        CellIdentifier= @"MyCell";


        MyCell *cell =(MytCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        if (!cell) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];                 cell = myCell;


        }
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
```

OK, I got it
it's  cell.contentView.backgroundColor.

Answer (score 1):

Because of cell caching, you should be changing the background color in the delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
}
```

cell.backgroundColor will show up properly in this method.

Comment: Is there any possibility to unload the cell-cache? reload does not clear the cell cache.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to load the cell from a nib but are never actually setting the nib to `MyCell`

Try changing to this:

```
   if (!cell) {
       cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
   }
```

Comment: cannot, cell=  because the bundle and nib output an NSArray  not a cell. My code works.    no worry, I able to load my custom cell into the table.  I just want to how to change the row color of the tableview.

Comment: Notice I put `objectAtIndex:0` at the end.  This loads the first view in the nib.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your cell is loading, and only background color is not changing, I think your other elements in  your custom cell MyCell are covering the cell background view.

try setting the bacgroundcolor of all other elements in the cell to red/yellow, and see if there is any of the cell.Background visibile.

btw: why not set the background color in your custom cell?

Comment: what do you mean it wont work? did you try setting the other views inside the label to clear color or some other color (red/yellow since it'd contrast with blue)?